# Simple way to generate syslog over TCP?

Tags: command-line, syslog

I want to troubleshoot logstash server issue and need to generate syslog message from time to time. Is there a simple way that allows me to connect to a syslog server using TCP and send some arbitrary syslog messages?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Netcat

Send each line of `file.log` towards syslog server `127.0.0.1` on port `514`

```
nc -q0 127.0.0.1 514 < file.log
```

Send a simple string that will generate a single log entry:

```
echo "message" | nc -q0 127.0.0.1 514
```

---

`-q0` makes `nc` exit after sending:

> -q seconds   after EOF on stdin, wait the specified number of seconds and then quit.

### Tcpflood

The [tcpflood](http://www.rsyslog.com/tag/tcpflood/) utility has quite a lot of useful options. Below is a small subset of `tcpflood` options:

```
-t  target address (default 127.0.0.1)
-p  target port (default 13514)
-c  number of connections (default 1)
-m  number of messages to send (connection is random)
-M  the message to be sent. Disables all message format options, as only that exact same message is sent.
-I  read specified input file, do NOT generate own test data. The test completes when eof is reached.
-D  randomly drop and re-establish connections. Useful for stress-testing the TCP receiver.
-T  transport to use. Currently supported: "udp", "tcp" (default) Note: UDP supports a single target port, only
```

Comment: You may add [Nping](https://nmap.org/nping/) to generate that TCP packets.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize syslog protocol is so simple. Even telnet works!

Comment: Not sure if this has to be edited, i have nmap-ncat package and its `--send-only` versus `-q0`